# ScrollView Animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a `ScrollView` in which i have layout as its child.What i am loading each layout within the `ScrollView` one by one using `android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout"`where layout is a `anim` file.
Here is the anim file

```
  <layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:delay="200%"
     android:animation="@anim/slide_in_up" />
```

and for `slide_in_up` here is the file ::

```
 <translate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromYDelta="100%p"
    android:toYDelta="0"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime" />
```

Now the Issue is that i want to apply the same While Scrolling happens.
As User Scroll  all the layout should come one after other.I came across `Scroller` class but i no example of it.Is there anyway to achieve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Scrollview, consider using a Listview. In the listview's source adapter implementation override getView(..) and apply your desired animation to that view. This should help: 
http://rimkhong9.blogspot.jp/2012/07/androidlistviewlistview.html